# What is an alternative to Chi-Square for observed vs. expected variance suitable for repeated measures?

Tags: variance, repeated-measures, glmm, overdispersion, mcnemar-test

I want to test for individual-level side preference of a behaviour during an experiment, and found a way to do this using a chi-square test that uses the number of right (or left) turns out of the ten trials of an individual and compares the observed variance in the data to the expected variance, to see if the data has more extreme values than expected.

```r
chi_sq = ((N-1)*var(X1)/(n*0.5*0.5) 
pchisq(chisq, df=(N-1), lower.tail=FALSE)
```

"In which N is the total number of individuals, n is the number of trials per individual (10) and X1 is a column in a data frame corresponding to the number of right (or left) turns per individual (each row of data frame represents one individual)"

My approach is very similar, but unlike this setup, I measured lateralisation at three time points during development. Like this method, I would like to test whether I have more observations in the tailends of the overall distribution than expected by chance, but for my dataset with its repeated measures. I would also like to include time as an independent variable to see whether variance varies significantly across the three timepoints. Here is an example of what this part of my data looks like:

\begin{array}{| c | c | c |}
     \hline
     \text{individual}&\text{right turns} &\text{time}\\
     \hline
     1  & 8 & 1\\
     1  & 6 & 2\\
     1  & 5 & 3\\
     2  & 3 & 1\\
     2  & 1 & 2\\
     2  & 4 & 3\\
     \hline
\end{array}

Additionally, I don't have a total of ten turns per block for every individual and some individuals died between time periods and new ones were added. I can exclude these cases though if including them is not possible.
Is there a way to do this? I've found the McNemar test and generalized versions and thought a glmm could work, but I am not sure how to use those for variance and adapt them to my data.

(method described here from Roche et al. (2020))